# Why do we need to download programs from the internet to program?

Tags: compiler-construction, libraries

I have tried different things in different languages for a couple of years and in everything I do, you need to download a multitude of different softwares that enable you to begin programming. Such as libraries, compilers, addons ect. Is it possible to open up notepad, program a compiler for c++ and then work your way from there? Or is downloading software absolutely necessary?

Comment: "is downloading software absolutely necessary" - obviously, because no software existed before the internet did?

Comment: The `compiler construction` tag is wrong. You are not coding a compiler (just wanting to use one).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid downloading software? Please edit your question to explain that!

Comment: You don't have to. Construct your bootstrap compiler by writing binary machine code that can parse your source. Start small (maybe variable declarations) and proceed through generations of your bootstrap until which point you can compile a new compiler written in your new language (a.k.a. self-hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need (in principle) to download programs to learn programming. I started to code in 1974, before Internet was available.

You program by writing [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) in some [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language). Your source code needs to be handled by some program, which is either a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) or an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)). And you need something to give you the ability of typing source code (an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) with a [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system), a source code editor, a file manager, ....).

That compiler or interpreter should exist on your computer (and you also need some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) in practice).

You could buy a computer with an operating system, a compiler (or many of them) and/or an interpreter installed on it (your vendor would probably do the downloading and installation, and you'll pay him for that work). For example, many [Linux distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) have all that (and I recommend using Linux to learn programming, it is very student- and developer- friendly).

<sup>For commercial reasons, Windows is not installed with all these.</sup>

In practice, you need many other programs to write code comfortably ([source code editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor), [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) systems, [command line interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface), [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), [debuggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger), [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools, various software utilities).

> you need to download a multitude of different softwares that enable you to begin programming.

Some programming environment are more friendly ; e.g. [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/) is probably packaging several tools together.

If you code in C++, don't confuse the [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) you are using with your C++ compiler. Your IDE is likely to run a compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) for you behind your back, and you'll better be able to run your C++ compiler on the command line. You generally want to enable all warnings and debug info, so with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you'll compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`.

> Is it possible to open up notepad,

Better learn to use a good, real, [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)).  If coding in C++, you want [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting), automatic [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and [prettyprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint), [autocompletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete), [brace matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_matching), etc.... and you'll configure your editor to suit your needs.

> program a compiler for c++

Wrong terminology. You don't *program* a compiler, you just *use* an existing C++ one. In practice, C and C++ compilers are [very complex](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065) pieces of software (because they are [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)), of many millions lines of source code. Both [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C++ compilers (coded in C++ so [bootstrapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers))); you can download their source code and study and improve it (you'll need years of work for that).

Comment: Most modern windows editions have bundled some version of .NET Framework which includes, at the least, the C# and VB.Net compilers. You don't need a compiler *and* an interpreter, so I'm not sure what you consider windows to be missing.

Comment: I never used Windows, so I don't really know. AFAIK C++ compilers are not given by default, but I could be wrong.